# Show a popup in form submit

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, forms, popup

I have a custom module with a frontend form. How is it possible to show a popup after submitting the form? Please give a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please check this link might be useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176189/magento-how-to-display-product-in-popup-onclick/176657#176657

Comment: Please refer the following link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181776/success-message-in-popup

Answer (score 4):

Follow this step

1. Submit form Using ajax
2. on ajax success open popup

Comment: I have changed the form submission using ajax. But how is it possible to display the popup on ajax success.This is my script. 
complete: function(response) {   
            alert("success");
            jQuery.fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 450,
                maxHeight   : 350,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
            });           
        },

alert("success") is working. But popup is not loading. Please help.

Comment: edit your question and peste your code so it is visible clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can call function onClick event of form button and in that function display/show modal using jQuery.